# Time Complexity of Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I need help with finding out the time complexity of the following algorithm:

```
procedure VeryOdd(integer n):
for i from 1 to n do
  if i is odd then
    for j from i to n do
      x = x + 1
    for j from 1 to i do
      y = y + 1
```

This is my attempt:

$$ Loop1 = \Theta(n)$$
$$ Loop2 = \Theta(n)$$
$$ Loop2 = O(n)$$

And we also know that loop2 and loop3 will get executed every second time of the execution of the outer loop. So we know that:

$$T(n) = \Theta(n) * 1/2(\Theta(n) + O(n)) = \Theta(n^2)$$

Now to the thing I'm not so sure about, nameley, is Loop3 really $$O(N)$$ and
if yes, then is $$\Theta(n) + O(n) = \Theta(n)$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that loops 2 does *something* $n+1-i$ times and loop 3 does *something* $i$ times, so you can just take them as a single loop, repeated $n+1$ times.

Comment: Please take care in the future to use text instead of image files. Also, similar things have been covered multiple times (see e.g. [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/14124/98) or, more generally, [tag:runtime-analysis]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 
Loop 1 = \theta(n) 
$$
Since both loop in total will run n times so,
$$
Loop 2 + Loop3 = \theta(n)
$$
$$
T(n) = \theta(n) * 1/2 ( \theta(n)) = \theta(n^2)
$$

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question, is it also true that loops 2 and 3 belongs to O(n) and also Omega(n) ? Thanks

Comment: You can write but then it will not be a tight analysis and some people may not like this because it is clear that in total 2nd and 3rd loop will run n-times no more and no less ,then theta(n) is correct..

Comment: But the second and 3rd loop will right n+1 times ?

Comment: Yes I wrote it n my mistake, but still it will be theta(n) ..